# custom select type customer attribute not showing magento2

Tags: magento2, custom, setup-upgrade, select

I am trying to create a custom select type of customer attribute for admin only. When I am running my upgradeData script, Its running fine and attribute created in the database, but not showing in admin customer form.

But If I am creating a text field instead of a select field then that showing fine at admin customer form.

Here is my code -

```
namespace Mynamespace\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    protected $eavSetup;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig,EavSetup $eavSetup)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
        $this->eavSetup = $eavSetup;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3', '<')){
            $this->eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_reseller_id');

            $this->eavSetup->addAttribute(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                'customer_reseller_id',
                [   
                    'type'      => 'int',
                    'label'     => 'Reseller',
                    'input'     => 'select',
                    'backend'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                    'source'    => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'visible'   => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'position'  => 160,
                    'sort_order'=> 160,
                    'system'    => false
                ]
            );

            $customAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                'customer_reseller_id'
            );

            $customAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                ['adminhtml_customer']
            );

            $customAttribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
[
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Reseller',
    'input' => 'select',
    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
    'required' => true,
    'default' => '0',
    'sort_order' => 160,
    'system' => false,
    'position' => 160,
    'adminhtml_only' => 1,
    'option' =>
         array (
            'values' =>
                 array (
                     0 => 'Custom val 1',
                     1 => 'Custom val 2',
                     2 => 'Custom val 3',
                 ),
         ),
]
```

Update

```
$customAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                ['adminhtml_customer']
            );
```

With:

```
$customAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']
            );
```

Comment: But I only need in admin customer form, then why I put the other form's name in the array. One more thing if this is the issue the why "text" type attribute showing in same way.

Comment: Adding `'adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'` in `used_in_forms` doesn't add the attribute in front automatically ! you need for that to add the field in phtml, Since you only want it on admin, so leave it like this.